# How to count all the letters, digits and special symbols from a given string?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, output, symbols

looking for sum of letters, digits and symbols separately.

```
def find_digits_chars_symbols(a):
    letters = 0
    digits = 0
    symbols = 0
    for i in a:
        if "A"<=i <= "z" :
            letters += 1

        elif "0"<=i <= "9":
            digits +=1

        else:
            symbol += 1
            
    print("Letters=",letters)
    print("Digits=",digits)
    print("Symbols=",symbols)
```

getting blank output

Comment: `if "A"<=i <= "z"` does not do what you want it to do. You need to explicitly define the characters (see the [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) module), then use the `in` operator to see if the current char is in that group.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) and [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python standard `string` module in combination with the sum function to count the number of occurences.

```py
import string

def find_digits_chars_symbols(a):
    letters = sum((ch in string.ascii_lowercase+string.ascii_uppercase) for ch in a)
    digits = sum((ch in string.digits) for ch in a)
    symbols = sum((ch in string.punctuation) for ch in a)
    print("Letters=",letters)
    print("Digits=",digits)
    print("Symbols=",symbols)
```

Comment: Are symbols necessarily punctuation? It seems `symbols = len(a) - letters - digits` would be safer.